# Azure Automation: Service Principal account from different tenant authenticates but doesn't return service principal

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-rm

I'm having issues executing a runbook aon a subscription in a different tenant.

This is what I have done so far:

1) Created a keyvault cert.
2) Exported .cer and .PFX of certificate.
3) Created a Service Principal on the rpgorch-aad account (300eab96-4619-4b6b-af42-8eb66506ab04)
4) Created a connection in Automation with that service principal's information
5) Uploaded password protected PFX to Automation certificate store

First, a working example from within the same tenant:

```
    $connectionName = 'AzureRunasConnection'
"Getting Azure Connection $connectionName"
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
"Logging in to Azure using Add-AzureRmAccount"
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal `
    -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint -Verbose

"Setting Context with Set-AzureRmContext"
Set-AzureRmContext -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID -SubscriptionId $servicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionId -Verbose
"Writing Output of the Service Principal Connection"
 write-output $servicePrincipalConnection

"Testing getting resource groups."
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup
```

**Results:**

```
Getting Azure Connection AzureRunasConnection  
Logging in to Azure using Add-AzureRmAccount  

PSComputerName        : localhost  
PSSourceJobInstanceId : Redacted  
Environments          : {AzureCloud, AzureChinaCloud, AzureUSGovernment}  
Context               : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext  

Setting Context with Set-AzureRmContext  
PSComputerName        : localhost  
PSSourceJobInstanceId : Redacted  
Account               : Redacted  
Environment           : AzureCloud  
Subscription          : Redacted  
Tenant                : Redacted  

Writing Output of the Service Principal Connection  

Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
SubscriptionId                 Redacted                                                     
TenantId                       Redacted                                                     
ApplicationId                  Redacted                                                     
CertificateThumbprint          Redacted                                                 


Testing getting resource groups.

PSComputerName        : localhost  
PSSourceJobInstanceId : Redacted  
ResourceGroupName     : Redacted  
Location              : eastus  
Resources             :   
ResourcesTable        :   
ProvisioningState     : Succeeded  
Tags                  : {}  
TagsTable             :   
ResourceId            : /subscriptions/Redacted/resourceGroups/Redacted
```

Now the SAME code, but for the other tenant.

```
$connectionName = 'Redacted'
"Getting Azure Connection"  
$connectionName

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName 

"Logging in to Azure using Add-AzureRmAccount"
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal `
    -Tenant $Conn.TenantID `
    -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint -Verbose

"Setting Context with Set-AzureRmContext"
Set-AzureRmContext -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionId -Verbose

"Selecting subscriptionID "
$Conn.SubscriptionID
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID 

"Testing getting resource groups."
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup
```

**Results:**

```
Getting Azure Connection
RPGOrchResourceManagement

Logging in to Azure using Add-AzureRmAccount

Results: 
PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : Redacted
Environments          : {AzureCloud, AzureChinaCloud, AzureUSGovernment}
Context               : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext

              Setting Context with Set-AzureRmContext
Set-AzureRmContext : Provided subscription Redacted does not exist
At ManageSingleVM:52 char:52
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand

PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : Redacted
Environments          : {AzureCloud, AzureChinaCloud, AzureUSGovernment}
Context               : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext

              Setting Context with Set-AzureRmContext
Set-AzureRmContext : Provided subscription Redacted does not exist
At ManageSingleVM:52 char:52
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand
```

Comment: 1. Is this service principal Multi-tenant ? 2. Did the user/admin from the other tenant do consent  for your sp?

Comment: Yes the SP is multi-tenant and I am the admin.

Comment: Did you do admin consent for the permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate on how you would provide admin consent?

Comment: Hi @M.Walters , I mean that when the admin in the other tenant  try to accees your app the first time, admin will be required to do admin consent for some permissions. Did you do admin consent in the other tenant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this. For anyone else looking, I needed to run this command on the Application ID:

```
        New-AzureRMRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $ApplicationId | Write-Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```